# Convert id to Number format

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

How to convert `2.79470525274901e+28` id to number in Java Script?

Answer (score 0):

You can pass it to `new Number()`:

```js
const a = new Number('1e+5');
```

This will make it a number object. It'll work just like a normal number, and then you can do other things with it:

```js
const a = new Number('1e+5') + 5;
console.log(a);
```

Do note, that if that is an `id`, meaning it's a really long number, then you'll probably have issues. If you take something like this:

```
2.79375892768972378067309875980271598721390687239086729387698
```

it'll turn into something like this:

```
2.792573895732e+30 // didn't actually count, just an example
```

However, when it's converted back, everything after that last 2 gets turned into a zero:

```
2.79257389573200000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
```

This is due to the limits of precision of JavaScript's number.

Thus, if that ID is a number and not just a string that looks like a number, there would be no way to restore it to its original form.